# css url function OR operator

Tags: css, url, operator-keyword

Hi I want to know if I can use OR operator in CSS url function.

Example: 
Is this possible ?

```
happy.moods {
    background-image: url( 'pathA/img.png' || 'pathB/img.png' );
}
```

Comment: No, but what are you trying to achieve? Multiple background images? If so, use multiple urls separated by commas. `url(pic1), url(pic2)`. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds).

Comment: If on the other hand you mean "try one image, if it doesn't exist try the other", then you're out of luck. While the above syntax would be possible for when only one of the pictures would exist, it would still show both if both existed.

Comment: @MrLister It is the second case you describe that I'm trying to achieve. Thanks for the comment. I need a smarter way to manage my files then.

Answer (score 0):

As some other users pointed out in the comments, there is no way to do what you speak of. While we can set things like `min-width` and `max-width` to achieve some half-baked logic, CSS and HTML really does not have a concept of logic at all. Even with psuedo-class selectors, the logic for displaying changes in a webpage is not a property of the code you have written but a property of *the web browser*.

This is why you can literally write any thing (regardless of whether it is proper code or not) into an HTML or CSS file and it won't cause the program to "break" because there is nothing to "compile".

However, this is where some concepts of Javascript come into play. I'm going to assume that you want a dynamic background image, if so, just go ahead and search that on SO or on Google, there are multiple pages out there to help you out.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's very helpful.